# I am trying to locate an element with a dynamically generated number at the end after each build

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify an image. It is given as

```
src="/Content/Images/connected-large.png?v=34r23".
```

In the above `src`, the last 5 alpha numeric characters will dynamically change after each build.

```
if (driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[src='/Content/Images/connected-large.png?v=34r23']")).Count == 0)
{
    WriteFail("Message");
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

I tried the above to verify but due that dynamic generated alpha numeric characters, after every new build I am changing that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you shove the build number (assuming that's what this is) in the .config file post-build and pull it from there in the code? Not that this is a great approach, but...

Comment: Your code doesn't seems to verify that. It is looking for count==0.

Comment: I dont think so, because that image represents a color, so we use 3 colors for identification. So each will get a random number everytime.

Comment: no, it is. if the count of that element is equal to zero then it fails.

Comment: using css as `src*='/Content/Images/connected-large.png'` wont help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath - contains / starts-with.

```
//img[contains(@src,'/Content/Images/connected-large.png?v=')]

if (driver.FindElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/Content/Images/connected-large.png?v=')]")).Count == 0)
{
WriteFail("Message");
Assert.Fail();
}
```